# Errors when updating Angular 4 to Angular 5 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core

Since Angular 5 is in stable stage I am updating Angular 4 to Angular 5 in Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.NET Core Application.

I don't want to use the template because the application is already in Angular 4 running in production.

When I updated to Angular 5, I receive lots of errors. I followed the link in the official site - https://angular.io/guide/setup.

Here is the *TS.Config* File

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "rootDir": "app",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

*Package.json*

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "~5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~5.0.1",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.5.1",
    "systemjs": "0.20.19",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

*Errors*

> Error TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'.
>   Error TS2428  Build:All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical
>   type parameters. Error    TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier
>   'PropertyKey'.     Error  TS2428  Build:All declarations of 'WeakMap' must
>   have identical type parameters.    Error  TS2428  Build:All declarations
>   of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters. 
>   Error TS2375  Build:Duplicate number index signature. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2374  Build:Duplicate string index signature. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'main' must be of type 'any', but here has type
>   'NodeModule'. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable
>   declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'parent' must be of
>   type 'any', but here has type 'NodeModule'.   FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'children' must be of type 'any[]', but here has type
>   'NodeModule[]'.   FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier
>   'BufferEncoding'. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent
>   variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'errno' must
>   be of type 'string', but here has type 'number'.  FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'stdout' must be of type 'WritableStream', but here
>   has type 'WriteStream'.   FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent
>   variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'stderr' must
>   be of type 'WritableStream', but here has type
>   'WriteStream'.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable
>   declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'stdin' must be of
>   type 'ReadableStream', but here has type 'ReadStream'.    FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'platform' must be of type 'string', but here has type
>   'Platform'.   FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier
>   'Buffer'. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier
>   'SlowBuffer'. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2415  Build:Class 'EventEmitter'
>   incorrectly extends base class 'internal'.    FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2309  Build:An export assignment cannot be used in a module
>   with other exported elements. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'port' must be of type 'number', but here has type
>   'string | number'.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent
>   variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'headers'
>   must be of type '{ [key: string]: any; }', but here has type
>   'OutgoingHttpHeaders'.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent
>   variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable
>   'httpVersionMajor' must be of type 'string', but here has type
>   'number'. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable
>   declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'httpVersionMinor'
>   must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number'. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'connection' must be of type 'any', but here has type
>   'Socket'. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable
>   declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'headers' must be of
>   type 'any', but here has type 'IncomingHttpHeaders'.  FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'trailers' must be of type 'any', but here has type
>   'OutgoingHttpHeaders'.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent
>   variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'rawTrailers'
>   must be of type 'any', but here has type 'string[]'.  FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier 'Agent'. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'addressType' must be of type 'string', but here has
>   type 'number | "udp4" | "udp6"'.  FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier 'Worker'.    FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable 'constants' must be of type '{ UV_UDP_REUSEADDR:
>   number; errno: { SIGHUP: number; SIGINT: number; SIGQUIT: number;
>   SIGILL: num...', but here has type '{ UV_UDP_REUSEADDR: number;
>   signals: { SIGHUP: number; SIGINT: number; SIGQUIT: number; SIGILL:
>   n...'.    FalconWebsite   D:\Ecommerce\FalconWebsite\FalconWebsite\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts    1312
>   Error TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier
>   'CompleterResult'.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate
>   identifier 'Script'.  FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent
>   variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Socket' must
>   be of type 'new (options?: { fd?: string; type?: string;
>   allowHalfOpen?: boolean; }) => Socket', but here has type 'new
>   (options?: { fd?: number; allowHalfOpen?: boolean; readable?: boolean;
>   writable?: boolean;
>   })...'.   FalconWebsite   D:\Ecommerce\FalconWebsite\FalconWebsite\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts    2192
>   Error TS2451  Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable
>   'constants'.  FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier
>   'TLSSocket'.  FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier
>   'Utf8AsciiLatin1Encoding'.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate
>   identifier 'HexBase64Latin1Encoding'. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier
>   'Utf8AsciiBinaryEncoding'.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate
>   identifier 'HexBase64BinaryEncoding'. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier
>   'ECDHKeyFormat'.  FalconWebsite    Error  TS2420  Build:Class 'Readable'
>   incorrectly implements interface 'ReadableStream'.    FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2420  Build:Class 'Writable' incorrectly implements interface
>   'WritableStream'. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate
>   identifier 'export='. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate
>   identifier 'export='. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate
>   identifier 'Domain'.  FalconWebsite    Error  TS2420  Build:Class 'Domain'
>   incorrectly implements interface 'NodeJS.Domain'. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier 'export='.   FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier 'export='.   FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.   FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'name' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable
>   declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.unscopables]'
>   must be of type '{ copyWithin: boolean; entries: boolean; fill:
>   boolean; find: boolean; findIndex: boolean; keys: ...', but here has
>   type 'any'.   FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   'flags' must have identical modifiers.    FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'EPSILON' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER' must have
>   identical modifiers.  FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent
>   variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable
>   '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type '"Symbol"', but here has type
>   'string'. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   'hasInstance' must have identical modifiers.  FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'isConcatSpreadable' must have
>   identical modifiers.  FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All
>   declarations of 'iterator' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   'match' must have identical modifiers.    FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'replace' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   'search' must have identical modifiers.   FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'species' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   'split' must have identical modifiers.    FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'toPrimitive' must have
>   identical modifiers.  FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All
>   declarations of 'toStringTag' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   'unscopables' must have identical modifiers.  FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same
>   type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type '"Math"', but
>   here has type 'string'.   FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All
>   declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable
>   declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]'
>   must be of type '"JSON"', but here has type 'string'. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must
>   have identical modifiers. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All
>   declarations of 'size' must have identical modifiers. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   'size' must have identical modifiers. FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2428  Build:All declarations of
>   'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters.    FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2344  Build:Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint
>   'object'. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2344  Build:Type 'K' does not satisfy
>   the constraint 'object'.  FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent
>   variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'prototype'
>   must be of type 'WeakMap', but here has type
>   'WeakMap'.  FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All
>   declarations of 'prototype' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2403  Build:Subsequent variable
>   declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'prototype' must be of
>   type 'WeakSet', but here has type
>   'WeakSet'.   FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   'prototype' must have identical modifiers.    FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2687  Build:All declarations of 'value' must have identical
>   modifiers.    FalconWebsite    Error  TS2687  Build:All declarations of
>   'prototype' must have identical modifiers.    FalconWebsite
>   Error TS2300  Build:Duplicate identifier
>   'BufferEncoding'. FalconWebsite    Error  TS2300  Build:Duplicate
>   identifier 'EventEmitter'.    FalconWebsite

Comment: In https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1221503/Angular-and-NET-Core-with-Visual-Studio you have as change Angular 4 to Angular 5. NOTE: You must add "core-js": "^2.4.1" in your package.json in order to can use HttpClientModule.

Comment: I have added core-js - 2.5.1 as you can see in the package.json

Comment: Angular 5 requires a minimum of TypeScript 2.4 as documented in the releases notes as well as a minimum of rxjs 5.5.0

Comment: newer typescript also may mean, that you can't have a "node_module" folder in one of the parent folders if your project otherwise you need adjustments to your tsconfig.json

Comment: from the article: "we need to modify the webpack.config.js Why? Because the Angular 4 and below support AOT compiler but Angular 5 and above do no support AOT compile while deployment"